The Network Connection Was Lost
I'm using travelpayouts API and unfortunately I'm getting:

"The Network Connection Was Lost"

It used to work fine and I haven't changed a thing and it started happening. I'm using a physical device. It started showing this error on simulators and physical device. It sometimes functions probably but now 95% of the time it does not.
func getFlightsRoot(destinationAirports: [Airport], departureAirports: [Airport], destinationAirport: Airport, departureAirport: Airport, departureDate: String, arrivalDate: String, adultsCount: Int, IPAddress: String, budget: Int, isOneWay: Bool, iteration: Int = 0) {
    
    self.destinationAirports = destinationAirports
    self.departureAirports = departureAirports
    
    var flightClass = ""
    if (budget == 1 || budget == 2 || budget == 4) {
        flightClass = "Y"
    } else {
        flightClass = "C"
    }

    var signatureTemp = ""
    var signature = ""
    var segments: [FlightSegment] = []

    if isOneWay {
        signatureTemp = MD5("KEY):beta.aviasales.com:en-us:\(Marker):\(adultsCount):0:0:\(departureDate):\(destinationAirport.iata!):\(departureAirport.iata!):\(flightClass):\(IPAddress)")
        signature = signatureTemp.lowercased()
        segments = [
            FlightSegment(origin: departureAirport.iata!, destination: destinationAirport.iata!, date: departureDate)
        ]
    } else {
        signatureTemp = MD5("\(KEY):beta.aviasales.com:en-us:\(Marker):\(adultsCount):0:0:\(departureDate):\(destinationAirport.iata!):\(departureAirport.iata!):\(arrivalDate):\(departureAirport.iata!):\(destinationAirport.iata!):\(flightClass):\(IPAddress)")
        signature = signatureTemp.lowercased()
        segments = [
            FlightSegment(origin: departureAirport.iata!, destination: destinationAirport.iata!, date: departureDate),
            FlightSegment(origin: destinationAirport.iata!, destination: departureAirport.iata!, date: arrivalDate)
        ]
    }

    let request = FlightRequest(
        signature: signature,
        marker: "\(Marker)",
        host: "beta.aviasales.com",
        userIP: IPAddress,
        locale: "en-us",
        tripClass: flightClass,
        passengers: Passengers(adults: adultsCount, children: 0, infants: 0),
        segments: segments
    )

    let urlString = "https://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/flight_search"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        print("Invalid URL")
        return
    }

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

    // Encode request body
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    do {
        let jsonData = try encoder.encode(request)
        urlRequest.httpBody = jsonData
    } catch {
        print("Error encoding request: \(error)")
        return
    }

    // Set headers
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

   
    
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { [weak self] data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            
            self?.retryGetFlightsRoot(destinationDate: departureDate, arrivalDate: arrivalDate, adultsCount: adultsCount, IPAddress: IPAddress, budget: budget, isOneWay: isOneWay, iteration: iteration)
            
            print("ERROR in Flights API 1: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
           
            self?.retryGetFlightsRoot(destinationDate: departureDate, arrivalDate: arrivalDate, adultsCount: adultsCount, IPAddress: IPAddress, budget: budget, isOneWay: isOneWay, iteration: iteration)
            
          
            
            print("Error in Flights API 2: \(response as? HTTPURLResponse)")
            return
        }

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let responseData = try decoder.decode(FlightRootResponse.self, from: data)
            self?.currencyRates = responseData.currency_rates
            self?.searchID = responseData.search_id
            
            self?.getFlights(searchID: responseData.search_id, iteration: iteration, destinationDate: departureDate, arrivalDate: arrivalDate, adultsCount: adultsCount, IPAddress: IPAddress, budget: budget, isOneWay: isOneWay)
        } catch {
           
            self?.retryGetFlightsRoot(destinationDate: departureDate, arrivalDate: arrivalDate, adultsCount: adultsCount, IPAddress: IPAddress, budget: budget, isOneWay: isOneWay, iteration: iteration)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}


ERROR in Flights API 1: Optional("The network connection was lost.")


Use print(error) instead to get a more detailed error message.

ERROR in Flights API 1: Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=57, NSUnderlyingError=0x281c58060 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x283274c30 [0x1f759fb30]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100201bb6c9f661c0000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=57, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <26D642E2-E1F9-462F-BF15-1D0FF3141F6B>.<14>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(

Don't add information in comments. Instead, [edit] your post and add it there, where it can be formatted for readability and can be seen. Burying details in comments is useless.

The main resource I would point you to is here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1941/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017602
Chances are, you'll need to look in the server-side logs, because if it is happening that frequently, the connection is probably being closed on the server side, rather than caused by a network error.  That or somebody enabled low data mode. turned off cellular access for your app, or turned off data roaming.
Another possibility is that your uploaded data itself has changed over time, and has grown so big that you have a high probability of the upload timing out over a slow cellular link.
If neither of those applies, then the only thing you can really do is use a network analyzer to capture packet traces, see if you can figure out what's happening, optionally insert something like Charles Proxy inline to capture even more data, and then file a bug against iOS, assuming it doesn't turn out to be a server-side regression.
Note also that because these are POST requests (which are typically not idempotent), iOS cannot silently retry the request if it fails for any reason, so if you want any sort of retry logic, you'll have to implement that yourself in conjunction with whatever server state refresh might be needed, if applicable.
